# タグ [shellscript] のデフォルト・シンタックス・ハイライトを lang-sh にしたい

Tags: 機能の要求, シンタックスハイライト

タグ [shellscript](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shellscript) のデフォルトの[シンタックス・ハイライト設定](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2708/19110) (タグ wiki で「コード言語」と書かれているもの) が設定されていないことを見つけました。

ここは lang-sh に設定するのが適切だと思います。lang-sh に変えて良いでしょうか？

Comment: [csh] と [tcsh] にも設定されていないのを発見したのですが、これは lang-csh (内部実装的には lang-sh と同一) にすべきですかね……？　これらのシェルをあまり使わないので、bash のようなハイライトで良いのか分かりません。実際には[そこまでハイライトされない](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/453bd5f51e61245339b738b1bbdd42d7848722ba/src/prettify.js#L213)ので大丈夫なのでしょうか。

Comment: リンク記事を一瞥しかしておらず、いまいちよくわかっていないのが、この設定ってどこで管理されていて、どの単位で設定可能で、誰が設定可能なのか、ですね…

Comment: (英語を読むのは、、若干疲れる :(

Comment: @YukiInoue この設定はタグごとに設定可能で、モデレーターなら変更できます。各質問のデフォルトのハイライトはタグから決まっていて、その判断基準がこの「コード言語」です。

Comment: @YukiInoue そのうち和訳しておきますね :)

Comment: @YukiInoue 和訳しました: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2708/19110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

特に反対意見が無いようなので、[shellscript](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shellscript) のコード言語を lang-sh に設定しました ✔️

[image: コード言語が lang-sh に設定されているスクリーンショットです]